# JAXB-AXIS, When request xml is unmarshalled JAXB creates JAXBElement<Foo> object is creted instead of Foo Object

Tags: web-services, jaxb, axis

After doing a search abt the topic, i came to know by setting generateElementProperty=false  for JAXB bindings we can avoid this. But all the solutions shows how to set this property in a binding file and using the xjc command meaning when i create JAVA beans from schema file. But i want to know how can i set the property through API's or even a binding file which the APIS will read while unmarshalling my request xmls to create the request object(JAXBElement object instead of Foo Object).....

Thanks
Siva